# Performing a FetchRequest from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my new Swift app I am using a slide side menu with SWRevealViewcontroller.
On the rear view controller there are several fetch requests to retrieve the number of core data objects that meet some conditions. On the front view controller, the app user can create new core data objects.
In the normal way of using the app, the app user creates or modified the core data objects, and later he/she can reveal the rear view controller to see the number of objects of each type.

Please take a look of the two view controllers:

Front view controller:

[image]

If the user taps on the +button, a new object is created.
if the user taps on the menu button, the rear view controller is shown, as you may see in the image:
[image]

And now, finally my question: As you may see in the image, both view controllers are loaded and showed. I want to know if it is possible that on this scenario, with both view controllers on screen, if the +button is tapped on the right view controller, could I implement a way to perform the fetch requests on the left view controller to update the count of the objects of each type?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using a NSTimer on the rear view controller. I guess this is not the best solution, but it works. If the user taps on the +button to create a new object, the timer launches the fetch request to update the number of objects from each type.